# Making a div appear after certain point AND disappear after other certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

:)
I having some trouble hiding a DIV.

Scrolling donw, I can make it appear when a certain point is reached, BUT, I want to make it disappear when OTHER point is reached -- and, scrolling down, making it appear again.

I tried adding another var (with the name of the 3rd point) and I even made it disappear, BUT, when scrolling up again, it started blinking. :(

What is wrong? What should I do? :(

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#DIV1").hide(); //hide your div initially

var topOfOthDiv = $("#DIV2").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        $("#DIV1").fadeIn(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        $("#DIV1").fadeOut(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
});


});
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle too..

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xe3uv2sh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blinking because both of your if statements are true. So it is trying to fade in and fade out at the same time.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe3uv2sh/3/) to only fade in if you are between the two divs.

I changed it so it first checks if it is above the first div. If it is, then the special div is hidden. If you have scrolled past the first div, it then checks the position relative to the second div and shows or hides it.

So your code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#DIV1").hide(); //hide your div initially

    var topOfOthDiv1 = $("#DIV2").offset().top;
    var topOfOthDiv3 = $("#DIV3").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv1)
        {
             $("#DIV1").fadeOut(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
        else
        {
            if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv3) { //scrolled past the other div?
                $("#DIV1").fadeIn(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
            }
            else if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv3) { //scrolled past the other div?
                $("#DIV1").fadeOut(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: WOW, ALMOST THAT. I just need it to hide again when it passes DIV2 (just like it was, inicially)

Comment: :) What am I missing?

Comment: When you scroll up again, it does not hide when DIV2 is reached. On my original code, it does (just for reference ;D)

Comment: I've updated it. I think it matched what you want now :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done 100% with media queries

```
.selector {
    display: none; /*by default*/
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .selector {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the height is not fixed. So, the easier way (I think) is to trigger it when a div appears (one at the middle of the contend, other at the end).